# Como utilizar objetos em choices no django

Tags: python, django, modelagem

Tenho que criar models baseadas na seguinte UML:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente fiz o código de Experiencia dessa forma:

```py
class Experiencia(Base):
    ACADEMICA = 'AC'
    PROFISSIONAL = 'PR'
    TIPO_CHOICES = [
        (ACADEMICA, 'Acadêmica'),
        (PROFISSIONAL, 'Profissional'),
    ]
    candidato = models.ForeignKey(Candidato, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tipo = models.CharField(choices=TIPO_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    data_inicio = models.DateField()
    data_fim = models.DateField()
    observacao = models.TextField(max_length=400)
```

Estou em dǘuida em como colocar os objetos de `Academica` e de `Profissional` em `choices`, pois o que tem atualmente são apenas as strings. A mesta dúvida para `Tipo_curso`, como colocálo pra ser uma choice de `Academica`. E se tinha como usar polimorfismo de alguma forma nisso.

Comment: Vc está pensando em: quero gravar 'Experiencia Acadêmica' ou 'Experiência Profissional' ou usar a relação 'muitos pra muitos' (Acadêmica e Profissional) igual tá no diagrama?

Comment: @CarlosCortez Cada experiência pode ser apenas um: Academica ou profissional. E em outra classe eu tenho um campo que pode ter várias experiências. O que quero saber é como implementar pra Option de experiência referenciar profissional ou academica. Ou seja, quando eu indicar que a experiência é academica, como vou saber esses dados? Ex: instituição,curso. tenho a mesma dúvida pra Academica e TipoCurso.

Comment: Confesso q também gostaria de saber como faz essa alteração dinâmica usando só recurso python/django. O q eu já me deparei foi com manipulação via Java script nos forms/views, nunca diretamente nos models e em área administrativa. Vou tentar sobrescrever os templates e se conseguir alguma coisa, publico

Answer (score 2):

Eu prefiro usar da forma abaixo, pois dá uma separação visual.

**update**

Bibliotecas necessárias

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

**fim do update**

```
class Experiencia(models.Model):
    class ExperienciaChoices(models.TextChoices):
        AC = 'AC', _('Acadêmica')
        PR = 'PR', _('Profissional')

    candidato = models.ForeignKey(Candidato, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ExperienciaChoices.choices, default=ExperienciaChoices.AC)
    data_inicio = models.DateField()
    data_fim = models.DateField()
    observacao = models.TextField(max_length=400)

    objects = ExperienciaManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.candidato

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['candidato']
        verbose_name_plural = 'candidatos'


class ExperienciaManager(models.Manager):
    def conta_experiencia(self, keyword):
        return self.filter(tipo__icontains=keyword).count()
```

**Nota** Usando o *manager* permite com que você crie métodos que poderão ser utilizados com o `objects` conforme exemplo abaixo

```
total_de_academica = Experiencia.objects.conta_experiencia(‘AC’)
```

**Nota 2** Obviamente não estou levando em conta se esta é uma regra de negócio válida para seu caso. Apenas mostrando a funcionalidade.

Espero que ajude

Comment: A minha maior dúvida está mais relacionada ao acesso aos objetos academica e profissional. não vejo como seria possivel acessar dados deles após escolher um choice

Comment: Experiencia.objects.all() retorna uma "lista" de objetos do tipo Experiencia. Depois é só acessar os atributos... era isso?

Comment: Não, Experiencia.objects.all() vai me retornar candidato, tipo, etc. Queria saber como obter A experiência Academica por exemplo. Tenho um objeto do tipo Experiência, que tem como tipo Academica, como acesso os dados de Academica? curso, instituição etc. Repare que os choices de Experiência apontam pra classe Acadêmica.  O mesmo acontece de academica pra tipo curso.

Comment: Paulo, me dá uma luz! Haha onde eu colocaria essa 'total_de-academia'? No shell, é possível acessar tranquilamente e sem dificuldade mas no models (por exemplo) exibe mensagem de q a classe não oferece a opção objects

Comment: Não entendi bem sua questão. Usualmente vc fará o acesso ao método em uma view ou em uma camada de negócios, usualmente chamada de services.py, mas pode ter qualquer nome, alguns chamam de facade.py...

Comment: @PauloMarques cheguei no problema que imaginei que ia chegar, fiz uma questão pra ele, veja se entende melhor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/493218/como-mudar-inlines-de-acordo-com-um-option-no-django-admin