# Como mudar inlines de acordo com um option no django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Atualmente eu tenho o seguinte código:

```py
@admin.register(Experiencia)
class ExperienciaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('tipo', 'data_inicio', 'data_fim')

    inlines = [AcademicoInline, ProfissionalInline]

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        pass
```

Eu gostaria de registrar uma `Experiencia` para um usuário, mas o usuário pode escolher apenas uma, `Academica` ou `Profissional`. Eu gostaria de usar o campo `tipo` da `Experiencia` para fazer isso, quando o usuário escolher o tipo `academica`, mostrarei `AcademicaInline`, quando o usuário selecionar `profissional`, mostrarei `ProfissionalInline`. este registro precisa ser feito usando o módulo de administração django.

Tentei usar `get_inline_instances`, mas todas as minhas tentativas falharam.

mas models estão assim:

```py
class Experiencia(models.Model):
    ACADEMICA = 'AC'
    PROFISSIONAL = 'PR'
    TIPO_CHOICES = [
        (ACADEMICA, 'Acadêmica'),
        (PROFISSIONAL, 'Profissional'),
    ]
    tipo = models.CharField('Tipo', choices=TIPO_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    data_inicio = models.DateField('Data de início')
    data_fim = models.DateField('Data fim')


class Profissional(models.Model):
    empresa = models.CharField('Empresa', max_length=200)
    cargo = models.CharField('Cargo', max_length=200)
    remuneracao = models.FloatField('Remuneração')
    atividade = models.TextField('Atividade')
    experiencia = models.OneToOneField(Experiencia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Academica(models.Model):
    instituicao = models.CharField('Instituição', max_length=200)
    curso = models.CharField('Curso', max_length=200)
    experiencia = models.OneToOneField(Experiencia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Vi seu novo post agora. Acho que é [isso](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) que você quer.

Comment: Isso ai resolveria pelo front, Eu queria no painel de admin do django, eu não consegui resolver, a única maneira que encontrei é salvar o objeto e depois editalo novamente, ai consigo ver o campo academico ou profissional de acordo com o tipo informado.

Comment: Ué? Não seria apontar o form no ExperiênciaAdmin? Talvez [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789798/how-do-i-conditionally-change-the-django-admin-form-based-on-value-in-the-model) ajude